# Linking Docker container : Node.js + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I have a problem on linking 2 containers in development environment with Docker.

I have already my mongo container running calls db.

Here my Dockerfile for my Node app :

```
FROM nodesource/node:4.0

ADD package.json package.json  
RUN npm install  
ADD . .
ENV NODE_ENV development

CMD ["node","server.js"]
```

After building the the image I run it inside a linking container with the following command :

```
docker run --name myapp --link db:db_1 -p 80:3000 -d myapp
```

Here my two containers :

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND
>   CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS
>   NAMES 216304df0905        myapp               "node server.js"
>   25 minutes ago      Exited (1) 13 minutes ago
>   myapp 506f9fcfd30b        mongo               "/entrypoint.sh mongo"
>   19 hours ago        Up 19 hours                 27017/tcp           db

myapp logs :

> development
>
> Server running at http://localhost:3000
>
> /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
>           process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
>                                         ^ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)

It seems that the connection between my app and mongo doesn't work.

Someone can help me to deal with that ?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to establish a local mongodb connection from your logs. You need to use `db_1` as the hostname when connecting to the mongodb, when you are using linked containers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, mongoose will try to connect to a local mongodb.
To be able to use your mongodb container, you should use its hostname (db_1) while you make the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Sabmit you are right !

I just had to change this line of code into my config file:

db: 'mongodb://localhost/test'

by,

db: 'mongodb://db_1:27017/test'